# Standard JPEG quality of a picture taken with an iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, image, compression, jpeg

for my master thesis I need to know what the standard JPEG quality of a picture taken with an iPhone 6 or higher is. 
When taking pictures with it and retrieving the quality with ImageMagick, I get a quality of 92 for every picture.

However, I can't find any reference where this is stated...

Can someone help me finding a reliable source for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "quality" in JPEG. Some encoders use "quality" settings as a shorthand for quantization table selection. If two encoders have quality "92" they may not be the same setting within the JPEG stream.